# spaces affect the firefox commands in terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, firefox, gnome-terminal

```
firefox -private &
```

This command open private browsing . but the same command

`firefox -private&`

without space between ampersand and the -private option will only open normal browsing window.what is the difference between this two commands

Comment: Both commands do open private browsing.

Comment: Both will do the same thing. The shell will interpret `&` beforehand.

Comment: Both work for me. Are you sure the second command doesn't work for you?

Comment: Nuwan, heemayl, edwinksl. the first command only shows the private browsing icon, the second command open normal browsing windows. its not showing private browsing icon

Comment: @P.G.Krish Try `firefox --private-window &` and `firefox --private-window&`.

Comment: @edwinksl . yes its worked , but without window option 'firefox  -private&' it will not work

Comment: @P.G.Krish Yeah I eventually managed to reproduce your problem by running both commands consecutively (I had previously did the first one, closed the private window and then did the second one). This seems like an odd bug or there is something deep about how the command-line options are interpreted that I don't understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's [also been posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292369/spaces-affect-the-firefox-commands-in-terminal). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Gilles this site users only using ubuntu, but Unix & linux  site users from multiple Os , so i tried to check how this commands work in different Os